# Mac shuts down automatically

Tags: macbook-pro

Hi I am using MacBook 2008 model.

I've installed Win XP using Bootcamp.

For past few weeks I notice that when running Win XP, after few minutes (approx 15 to 20 mins), laptop gets shutdown automatically.

This does not happens when running OS X.

Any Suggestions...??

Comment: My best guess is that Windows is crashing. Try opening XP's logs and post them here.

Comment: This is a Diagnostic. Paste following in Terminal syslog -k Sender kernel -k Message CSeq 'n Cause: -' | tail | awk '/:/{$4=""; print}' | pbcopy  the result will be copied to your clipboard and tell us what is the reson for shut down.

Answer (score 1):

If the fans are running fast it's an overheating issue. Otherwise the windows battery related drivers might have a hard time detecting your battery state.